# how to avoid connecting to just one broker in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, load-balancing

We have deployed a broker cluster using P2P model.Data is spreaded over the whole cluster.Our many consumers use the same address "failover:(tcp://ip1:61616,tcp://ip2:61616,tcp://ip3:61616,tcp://ip4:61616,tcp:/ip5:61616)?nested.wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=1000"
.But at last,we find that many consumers will connect the same broker which makes data not on the broker transfered from other brokers.This transferring occupies bandwidth a lot.
how could I solve the balancing issue?And how consumer decide which broker to use?

For example,we have 3 brokers and all are configured with the following snippet:

```
<transportConnectors>       
     <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximum
Connections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" updateClusterClients="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" discoveryUri="multicast://default" />
</transportConnectors>

<networkConnectors>  
    <networkConnector  uri="multicast://default"/>  
</networkConnectors>
```

In the consumer program,I use "failover:(tcp://broker1:61616,tcp://broker2:61616)?nested.wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=1000" as the broker address.
I run three consumer processes,but find that all three processes connect to broker1IP finally which leads to the data in broker2 and broker3 is transferd to broker1 for consumption.
This leads to tremendous network burden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a loadbalancing for messages in brokers , you can use network of brokers to solve the issue , check out this link for further information http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

Comment: I have read the documentation and could not find a solution.I have updated my question description to clarify my question more.Thanks.

Comment: Use the discovery protocol to connect to the brokers instead of failover , you can find the explanation here at http://activemq.apache.org/discovery-transport-reference.html